# Null Reference Exception on Label in Site.Master

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why I'm getting Null Reference Exception on a Label that I have in my Site.Master page. I have 2 other labels on the same page, which are not throwing errors.

Here is the DIV with all 3 labels:

```
<div class="footer">
    <asp:Label ID="lblOS" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblFooter" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblFooterEx" runat="server" Text="<% $Resources:mobileResource,FooterExtra %>" />
</div>
```

The lblOS Label is the new one throwing the error.

Here is the code from my Site.Master.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Load App Store Icon
      string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
      if (lblOS.Text != null)
      { 
           if (strUserAgent.Contains("iphone") || strUserAgent.Contains("ipad")){
              lblOS.Text = "<a href='https://itunes.apple.com/'><img src='Images/appStore.jpg' class='connectIcons' title='App Store' alt='App Store' /></a><br />";
           }
           else{
               lblOS.Text = null;
           }
       }
       //Load Footer Links
       string url = Request.ServerVariables["URL"];
       url = url.Remove(0, url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

       if (url == "Default.aspx") {
          lblFooter.Text = GetGlobalResourceObject("mobileResource", "FooterNav").ToString();
       }
       else {
          lblFooter.Text = GetGlobalResourceObject("mobileResource", "FooterHome").ToString() + GetGlobalResourceObject("mobileResource", "FooterNav").ToString();
       }
}
```

The line "if (iOSLabel != null)" is the error.

As suggested elsewhere, I tried code noted [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and added:

```
Label iOSLabel = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblOS");
```

and altered the CS code accordingly.

When I tested it, that new iOSLabel is now throwing the null exception.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

**EDIT:**
Here is the error that's generated...

```
Error: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CLVmobileApp.SiteMaster.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Visual Studio\AS-MobileCLV\CLVmobileApp\Site.Master.cs:line 15
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\cbd2add4\2961a9ef\App_Web_ddrybdwm.17.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: where are you accessing that label ie. on MasterPage itself or content page?

Comment: The DIV with my labels are only on my Site.Master page. (It's my site's footer.)

Comment: I don't see that line with the error in your sample code.

Comment: I'm not sure what line you're referring to but I get the error on the line "if (lblOS.Text != null)" inside my Page_Load. I tried adding "Label iOSLabel = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblOS");" and changed all the "lblOS" to "iOSLabel" and the null reference exception is then on the "Label iOSLabel" line. No matter where I first reference that label, I get the error.

Comment: Does this error happen every time the page loads, or just sometimes?  Also, could you copy and paste the full text of the error message?  Something seems fishy about this.

Comment: It's happening sometimes. I cannot make it happen myself, but the errors are coming in from others using it. I'll edit my original post to add the error message that is generated and emailed.

Comment: This is one of those things where I imagine recompiling and republishing will fix the problem.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Just curious, were you ever able to resolve your issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Label iOSLabel = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblOS");
```

try

```
Label iOSLabel = (Label)(Master as MyMasterPage) .FindControl("lblOS");
```